# Bulk rename files based on the first line of their contents?

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, rename, filenames, batch-rename

I have a folder full of .java files, which I wish to rename. 
I want to rename the files with the first line of the contents of that file, with suffixes if the first line is same for two or more files?
I am running Windows 10.

Comment: You're going to really need a pretty good batch or bash (if you're using Cygwin) to do this.  I'd advise looking either a utility or coding this.  My guess it that you won't find many batch and/or programmers here.  While it isn't hard, you also might get a complaint that this isn't a script writing service.

Comment: Please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @DavidPostill Actually, I have no scripting experience. I thought it would be fine to ask the question here since there are similar questions on the site. Anyway, I found a way to get my work done in another way.
So, sorry for the bad question. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is a rough hack and there are probably better ways of doing this, but this should give you a starting point.  First, compile a list of the files you need with this command:

```
dir *.java /b >> dirlist.txt
```

You can probably do this part in the script, but creating this list first allows you more control over the files you will be operating on.

From that, the following JScript will read each line from that file, read the first line from that file, and rename the file accordingly:

```
var FSO = new ActiveXObject ('Scripting.FileSystemObject');
var fileList = FSO.OpenTextFile ('dirlist.txt');
var nextFileName, nextFile, newFileName;

while (!fileList.AtEndOfStream) {

  nextFileName = fileList.ReadLine();
  nextFile = FSO.OpenTextFile (nextFileName);
  newFileName = nextFile.ReadLine ();
  nextFile.Close();
  FSO.MoveFile (nextFileName, newFileName);

}
```

You will need to do some extra work to handle cases of duplicate names or where the first line needs some clean-up first, and this of course assumes that the script, the dirlist.txt file and all the .java files are in the same folder, but it should give you something to work with.

Hope this helps.